# ClientDataSet Next() doesn't navigate to the next record when updating the value of the primary key field in that dataset

Tags: delphi, c++builder, tclientdataset

Consider there is a clientdataset which is created for one of the table in the database.

Select GuestNo, ReportDate, SeqNo, GuestDetails from Guest.

[Here, **GuestNo**, **ReportDate** and **SeqNo** have the **Primary keys**]

I'm adding multiple records to the clientdataset,

```
cds->FieldByName("GuestNo")->AsInteger = 100;
cds->FieldByName("ReportDate")->AsDateTime = "2023-12-19";
cds->FieldByName("SeqNo")->AsInteger = 1;

cds->FieldByName("GuestNo")->AsInteger = 100;
cds->FieldByName("ReportDate")->AsDateTime = "2023-12-19";
cds->FieldByName("SeqNo")->AsInteger = 2;

cds->FieldByName("GuestNo")->AsInteger = 100;
cds->FieldByName("ReportDate")->AsDateTime = "2023-12-19";
cds->FieldByName("SeqNo")->AsInteger = 3;
```

but before posting the data to the database, I'm trying to update the ReportDate field in the clientdataset for all the records, where the field to be updated has a primary key in that table.

```
cds->First();
while (!cds->Eof)
{
    cds->Edit();
    cds->FieldByName("ReportDate")->AsDateTime = "2023-12-20";
    cds->Next();
}
```

In this case, when iterating through the records, after updating the field for the first record and then calling Next() doesn't navigate to the next record, and it ends the loop after the first iteration itself.
I assume that, since the field I'm updating has the primary key, after the updating the first record,
it looks up for the next record for the updated new date and therefore **cds->Eof** becomes true, since there is no record for the new date and it breaks out of the loop.

This is happening only when trying to update any of the field which is having primary key in that table but the other fields are updating fine.

Is there a way to change the value of the primary key field in the dataset, which has multiple records ?

I have tried by calling DisablingConstraints() for the dataset, but that doesn't work too.

Comment: Try going in the other direction (Last, Bof, Prior) if records are getting moved to the end after each edit. Note the order is determinted by whetaever index is active.

Comment: You should either switch to another index before updating or capture the records to be updated before doing the actual update. You can use bookmarks to capture each record and use a list of bookmarks to iterate through the dataset.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks. The Solution you have mentioned seems simple and worked for me, but why this is not working when I tried in the other way [First, Eof and Next] ??

Comment: @Ram When you change a value that is part of a key, and your dataset is sorted by that key, that record's position will likely change. Next() goes to the next record after the one you just edited. If changing the date moved that record to the end of the dataset, Next() will go to EOF. Brian's solution works in this instance, but will fail if the record moves to anywhere else in the dataset. As Kees says, it's better to use a different index, one that the field is not in, when you make changes of this nature. That way, your code will always work.